# Compare 2 array records containing comma seperated values

Tags: javascript

Here i am trying to compare Cars1 record with myArray record and if they are matching i want to set selected property to true of MyArray for matching record.

Abc.mp3,lmn.mp3,ggg.mp3 of myArray is matching with Abc.mp3,lmn.mp3 of cars1 as because Abc.mp3 is matching in both the array.

Here Abc.mp3,lmn.mp3,ggg.mp3 are 3 different records so after splitting by comma if any of the string is matching in cars1(split by comma) then 
set flag to true.

**Expected Output :**

```
var myArray = [
    {field: 'Abc.mp3,lmn.mp3,ggg.mp3', flag: true}, //Abc.mp3 is matching
    {field: 'kkk.mp3', flag: false},
    {field: 'Xyz.mp3', flag: true}, //Xyz.mp3 is matching
    {field: 'MMM.mp3,UUU.mp3', flag: true}, //UUU.mp3 is matching
];
```

```js
var myArray = [
    {field: 'Abc.mp3,lmn.mp3,ggg.mp3', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'kkk.mp3', flag: false},
    {field: 'Xyz.mp3', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'MMM.mp3,UUU.mp3', flag: false}, 
];

var cars1 = ["Abc.mp3,lmn.mp3", "Xyz.mp3","UUU.mp3"];

var cars2 = ["S1","S2","S3" ];

var array2 =[];

 var map = Object.create(null);
 cars1.forEach(function (entry, index) {
         map[entry] = index;
  });
 array2 = myArray.map(function (item) {
         var index = map[item.field];
         if (index === undefined) {
                return undefined;
         }
         item.flag = true;
         return cars2[index];
});
console.log(myArray);
```

**Update:**
Now cars1 and cars2 records have 1 to 1 relationship with each other that means Abc.mp3,lmn.mp3 of cars1 points to S1 of cars2 respectively.

While matching myarray with Cars1 if match found then i want to note index of cars1 and based on that index i would like to get record from cars2 and assign to array2 at that index position.

For eg:Abc.mp3,lmn.mp3,ggg.mp3 of myArray and Abc.mp3,lmn.mp3 of cars1 is matching so index of Abc.mp3,lmn.mp3 is 0 so based on this index get 0th index record from cars2 and assign to array2 at 0th index.for Xyz.mp3 S2 will be at 2nd position in array2.

**Expected output in array2 :**

```
array2 = ["S1" ,undefined, "S2","S3" ];
```

Comment: please clarify your question. Use **BOLD** and _Italic_ to format important sections

Comment: This question is pretty hard to follow, and it's not clear what your actual question is. So you need to go through `myArray` and if any of the comma delimited values in `field` match any of the comma delimited values is `cars1` then set `flag` to `true`, is that right? Then can we get rid of the irrelevent `cars2`? And do you need `array2` since you are mutating the original anyway (or was that not intended?).

Comment: @MattBurland : You are right for the first point and cars2 and array2 are important.see my update in which i have explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want something like this i think:

```js
function match(data, selectors) {
  return selectors.map(function(selector) {
    let matchedIndex = -1;
    return Object.assign({}, selector, {
      flag: data.some(function(item, index) {
        return selector.field.split(',').some(function(s) {
          if(item.split(',').indexOf(s) > -1) {
            matchedIndex = index;
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        });
      }),
      matchedIndex: matchedIndex
    });
  });
}



var myArray = [
    {field: 'Abc.mp3,lmn.mp3,ggg.mp3', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'kkk.mp3', flag: false},
    {field: 'Xyz.mp3', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'MMM.mp3,UUU.mp3', flag: false}, 
];
var cars = ["Abc.mp3,lmn.mp3", "Xyz.mp3","UUU.mp3"];
var cars2 = ["S1", "S2", "S3"];

var matched = match(cars, myArray);
var matchedFields = matched.filter(function(item) { return item.flag });



console.log(matched);
console.log(matchedFields);

var matchedCars2 = matched.map(function(item) { return cars2[item.matchedIndex]});
console.log('matched cars 2', matchedCars2);
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me.I have updated my question to include details for array2.can you update your answer to incorporate expected output for array2

Comment: Is there any use of matchedFields??

Comment: No. You can remove than if you don't need it.

Comment: This worked.can you please explain me this line :Object.assign({}, selector, ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
var myArray = [
    {field: 'Abc.mp3,lmn.mp3,ggg.mp3', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'kkk.mp3', flag: false},
    {field: 'Xyz.mp3', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'MMM.mp3,UUU.mp3', flag: false}, 
];

var cars1 = ["Abc.mp3,lmn.mp3", "Xyz.mp3","UUU.mp3"];

var carsHash = cars1.reduce(function(p,c) {
    var split = c.split(",");
    split.forEach(function(i) { p[i] = true; });
    return p;
},{});

myArray.forEach(function(i) {
    var split = i.field.split(",");
    i.flag = split.some(function(v) { return carsHash[v]; });
});

console.log(myArray);
```

First we create a hash will all the substrings from `cars1`. Then we just loop through `myArray` and if any of the substrings in `field` are present in `carsHash` we set the `i.flag` to true.